# Who is the physically-largest Force-sensitive being in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

As the title reads, who is the physically-largest (based on volume) Force-sensitive being in *Star Wars*?

Comment: What does "dimensions" mean? I wouldn't say I have any dimensions? Unless you're asking like chest, waist, hip dimensions. Or are you talking about height? What about the spirits that seem to be able to take any form?

Comment: Snoke is bloody massive; https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/36/590x/secondary/Star-Wars-8-Snoke-is-not-the-villain-it-is-this-main-character-1022652.jpg

Comment: @Edlothiad Updated the question.

Comment: I don't know my volume, would I know all the other star wars characters volumes? Do spirits have fixed volume? Same issues and what Skooba said. Did you even try google?

Comment: @Edlothiad You can easily compare your volume with that of an Elephant. Are there force-sensitive spirits in the canon? If yes, can they expand to infinite volume? BTW, Googling didn't help.

Comment: @Discovery Maybe you should *show* that it didn't help. possibly give us some examples of what you are (or are not) looking for....

Comment: @Skooba Searching "biggest force-sensitive character" shows strongest and most powerful force-sensitive characters. It's not worth including in the question.

Comment: As Skooba said, the things you've found that haven't been helpful would work as a guideline. Did links just not describe the detail? Have you tried searching "*Largest* force sensitive character" or using "-strongest" or "-powerful"

Comment: @Edlothiad Give it a break. If I am asking this question, it's inclusive that I failed to find answer from other sources. You can't force me to research your own way. Maybe, I don't use Google. If you don't like the question, simply downvote and move on.

Comment: There is a apparently a [Besalisk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Besalisk) who was a jedi.  This is the species of the big guy that ran the diner in _Attack of the Clones_.

Comment: What's unclear here? Some sort of mega-pedantry going on here, targeting these two size-related questions? Most people know what "biggest" means, and it only becomes a problem when you require some sort of encyclopedic definition of what "biggest" means.

Comment: @Valorum That's a holograph, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @CreationEdge - I see no evidence that it's not life-sized

Comment: @CreationEdge it’s the same pedantry that asked you to define “hate speech” or whatever it was

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The [“giants of living stone”](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Giants_of_living_stone)

Limiting ourselves to Disney canon, there are several large Force sensitives and even Force users (such as the [Bendu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bendu) and possibly the Zillo Beast). However, the largest would have to be the “giants of living stone,” enormous beings of blue stone, some the size of mountains, encountered by Yoda.

[image]

Besides being enormous, they also were imbued with the Force:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the Zillo beast, from the episode of the same name from *The Clone Wars*.  It's Godzilla-sized and can sense something bad about Palpatine, using the Force, I'd assume.

Comment: Or by smell. Maybe?

Comment: @valorum  Somewhere - maybe on TV Tropes?(I don't want to visit there from my office)  - I read that someone involved with the show had confirmed that the Zillo beast could sense the Dark Side radiating from Palpatine, and that was the source of its dislike.

Comment: You don't need to be a "Force-sensitive" to feel the evil emanating from a Sith. Leia's soldiers also feel the same when he boards the ship and Vader's Stormtroopers feel it when he comes aboard the Death Star. Everyone's a little bit sensitive to the Force but not everyone is a Force Sensitive.

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, but Sheev was hiding it (really well). So well that the Jedi couldn't sense it.

Comment: @Adamant - Cats can sense earthquakes.

Comment: @valorum Who knows?  Maybe, with training, we could have had a Zillo Beast Jedi... with 100m long lighsabers...  glorious!

Comment: @Valorum - …? The point is, it had a Force ability that allowed it to sense something that the Jedi couldn’t, something that was actively being concealed. That’s Force-sensitive enough for me.